# Targeted variable recoding in R

Tags: r, variables, data-manipulation

I am trying to do some text processing and need to recode the words of sentences so that a target word is identified in a particular way in the new variable. For instance, given a data frame that looks like this...

```
subj <- c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2")
condition <- c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B")
sentence <- c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2")
word <- c("I", "like", "dogs.", "We", "don't", "like", "this", "song.")
d <- data.frame(subj,condition, sentence, word)

 subj condition sentence  word
 1         A        1     I
 1         A        1     like
 1         A        1     dogs.
 2         B        2     We
 2         B        2     don't
 2         B        2     like
 2         B        2     this
 2         B        2     song.
```

I need to create a new column for which every instance of the target word (in this example, when d$word="like") is marked 0, and all words before "like" in the sentence block decrement and all words after "like" increment. Each subject has multiple sentences, and sentences vary by condition, so the loop needs to consider instances of the target word per subject, per sentence. The end result should look something like this.

```
 subj condition sentence  word   position
 1         A        1     I        -1
 1         A        1     like      0
 1         A        1     dogs.     1
 2         B        2     We       -2
 2         B        2     don't    -1
 2         B        2     like      0
 2         B        2     this      1
 2         B        2     song.     2
```

Sorry if the question is poorly worded, I hope it makes sense! Note that the target is not in the same place (relative to the start of the sentence) in each sentence. I am pretty new to R and can figure out how to increment or decrement, but not do both things within each sentence block. Any suggestions on the best way to go about this? Thanks much!

Comment: How do you decide if (for example) `We` is `-2` from the second `like` or `+2` from the first `like`?

Comment: @thelatemail, there is a column called `sentence` ;)

Comment: @RicardoSaporta - great, but what if the sentence is `I like the way you like to like things.`

Comment: @thelatemail, then presumably, the sentence would need to be split in to parts. However, I would guess that such preprocessing would be handled prior to determining relative positions.  Also, I like the way you like to like things too.

Comment: @thelatemail this was actually from an experimental manipulation so we had taken that into consideration, but yes, it wouldn't be a good way to code a corpus!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think in text processing that it would be wise to avoid letting your text entries become factors. In this case I used `as.character` but I would recommend setting `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`;

```
d$position <- with( d, ave(as.character(word), sentence, 
                               FUN=function(x) seq_along(x) - which(x=="like") ) )
> d
  subj condition sentence  word position
1    1         A        1     I       -1
2    1         A        1  like        0
3    1         A        1 dogs.        1
4    2         B        2    We       -2
5    2         B        2 don't       -1
6    2         B        2  like        0
7    2         B        2  this        1
8    2         B        2 song.        2
```

Answer (score 5):

You can add an index which you can then use for the relative positions.
Using `data.table` makes breaking it down by `sentence` very easy

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(indx=1:nrow(d), d, key="indx")

DT[, position:=(indx - indx[word=="like"]), by=sentence]

# Results
DT
#    indx subj condition sentence  word position
# 1:    1    1         A        1     I       -1
# 2:    2    1         A        1  like        0
# 3:    3    1         A        1 dogs.        1
# 4:    4    2         B        2    We       -2
# 5:    5    2         B        2 don't       -1
# 6:    6    2         B        2  like        0
# 7:    7    2         B        2  this        1
# 8:    8    2         B        2 song.        2
```

#### Udate:

In case  you have grammatically incorrect sentences, you might want to use `grepl` instead of `==`

```
DT[, position:=(indx - indx[grepl("like", word)]), by=sentence]
```

Comment: @alexwhan, I got turned onto it here on SO and it's absolutely incredible

Comment: Thank you, this looks great except I keep getting the following error: _Error in `[.data.frame`(DT, , `:=`(position, (indx - indx[grepl("like",  : 
  unused argument(s) (by = sentence)_  Not sure what the problem could be as I copied your code exactly...

Comment: did you install the `data.table` package and then call it using `library(data.table)`?

Comment: I did do that, yes! Might it have something to do with the data type of d$position? If I set this to factor or character I get a different error, _Combining := in j with by is not yet implemented. Please let maintainer('data.table') know if you are interested in this._

Comment: hi @amurphy, it sounds like the data you're working with is of different type than above.  Can you please `dput()` and post the output -- you can edit your question above, or, perhaps more appropriately, post it as a new question as a follow up, linking back to your previous question.

Answer (score 3):

Customary solution with `plyr`

```
 ddply(d, .(subj, condition, sentence), transform, 
   position = seq_along(word) - which(word == 'like'))
```